# PIL Image Resizing Script - Some image sizes won't scale properly

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

For work I have to resize hundreds of images to fit a 830x1000 pixel canvas while maintaining the aspect ratio (so the image is not stretched and distorted). I wrote a python script using PIL. This works for the majority of images but there are some image sizes that are distorted after running the script.

I know the issue lies in the case statement but I'm not sure exactly where it is.

```
def resize(): 
    openFiles = glob.glob('*.jpg')

    for files in openFiles:
        inFile = Image.open(files)
        fileName = os.path.splitext(files)[0] # gets filename
        outFile = fileName + ".jpg"
        print (fileName)
        print ("Original size ",inFile.size)
        xDim = inFile.size[0]
        yDim = inFile.size[1]        
        newSize = aspectRatio(xDim, yDim)       
        inFile = inFile.resize((int(newSize[0]),int(newSize[1])),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        inFile.save(outFile)
        print ("New Size ",inFile.size, "\n")

    return None


def aspectRatio(xDim, yDim):
    Ratio = float(xDim/yDim)
    xDelta = 830 - xDim
    yDelta = 1000 - yDim
    Oddball = [.99, .98, .97, .96, .95, .94, .93, .92, .91, .90, .89, .88, .87, .86, .85, .84, .83, .82, .81, .80]

    New1 = [xDim+xDelta, yDim+xDelta*Ratio]
    New2 = [xDim+yDelta*Ratio, yDim+yDelta]   

    if xDim == 830 and yDim == 1000:
        print('No Change Needed')
        return(xDim, yDim)

    if xDim == yDim:
       xDim = 830
       yDim = 830
       return(xDim, yDim)

    else:    
      if New1[0] == 830 and New1[1] <= 1000:
        xDim = float(New1[0])
        yDim = float(New1[1])
        return(xDim, yDim)

      elif New1[0] <= 830 and New1[1] <= 1000:
        xDim = float(New1[0])
        yDim = float(New1[1])
        return(xDim, yDim)

      elif New2[0] <= 830 and New2[1] ==1000:
        xDim = float(New2[0])
        yDim = float(New2[1])
        return(xDim, yDim)

      elif .83 < Ratio < 1:
        i = 0
        while xDim >= 830 and yDim >= 1000:  
          xDim = float(New2[0] * Oddball[i])
          yDim = float(New2[1] * Oddball[i])
          i =+ 1
          return(xDim,yDim)

        else:    
         print('Manual Change Required')
         return(xDim, yDim)
```

The following image sizes are the ones who are giving me issues right now.

Original size  (220, 643)
New Size  (830, 851)

Original size  (440, 617)
New Size  (830, 895)

Original size  (597, 480)
New Size  (830, 769)

Original size  (308, 631)
New Size  (830, 885)

Original size  (450, 625)
New Size  (830, 898)

Original size  (398, 631)
New Size  (830, 903)

Original size  (220, 643)
New Size  (830, 851)

Original size  (240, 643)
New Size  (830, 863)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, there is an easier way to implement aspectRatio()

```
fixed_ratio = 1000 / 830.0

def aspectRatio():
    curr_ratio = yDim *1.0 / xDim
    if curr_ratio <= fixed_ratio:
        return (830, 830 * curr_ratio)
    else:
        return (1000 / curr_ratio, 1000)
```

This fixed your issue.